# Coordinates of children inside a FlowPane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm attempting to write a GUI that presents five rectangles in a `FlowPane`, so that the user may click on them to select a character.

I use the following method to test whether the user has clicked inside a rectangle or not:

```
@FXML
private Rectangle characterA, characterB, characterC, characterD, character E;

private List<Rectangle> rects;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    rects = Arrays.asList(characterA, characterB, characterC, characterD, character E);
}

@FXML
private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    Rectangle rect;
    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
        rect = rects.get(i);
        if (rect.contains(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY())) {
            System.out.println("Clicked in rect " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is this: although on screen, the rectangles are laid out alongside each other, their coordinates are all apparently the same. Clicking on the first rectangle results in five copies of "Clicked in rect x", whilst clicking elsewhere gives no output at all.

How can I correctly determine which rectangle the user clicked in?

Comment: r1, r2 and r3 and not defined.

Comment: Oops, updated part of my code fragment and not the rest.

Comment: Can't you just register the mouse listener with the rectangles themselves, instead of with the flow pane?